# Work done when P,V, and T are changing simultaneously

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I am given the following P-V graph for an ideal gas:

[image: P-V graph]

I have been asked to find the work done in the process from C to A, for which $P$ is directly proportional to $V$. This may be calculated in two ways:

1. Work done= Area under the line CA, which is the area of the trapezium, given by

$$w = -\frac{1}{2}(P_0+2P_0)V_0 = -\frac{3P_0V_0}{2}$$

(where the negative sign has been introduced since the work done is negative due to decrease in volume.)

2. Work done = $\int -P\,\mathrm{d}v$. However, in this case, since $P$ is directly proportional to $V$, how to integrate this?

**How to calculate the work done in a process where all 3 variables, $P$, $V$, and $T$ are changing simultaneously and $P$ is directly proportional to $V$?**

Comment: Who said that $\ce{PV}$ is the work done?

Comment: The second method $\ce{P}\Delta\ce{V}$ only works when $P$ is constant, otherwise you should use integration.

Comment: Ohh, I see. But how to integrate for this case in which I can't substitute $P$=$nRT/V$ since $P$ is directly proportional to $V$?

Comment: It does not matter if $\ce{P}$ is directly proportional to $\ce{V}$. The energy is still $\displaystyle\frac23\int\ce{P}\ \mathrm d\ce{V}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how did you obtain that expression?

Comment: The energy is not $\ce{PV}$, but $\dfrac23\ce{PV}$. It is derived from the last formula of [this page](http://dev.physicslab.org/img/804cad92-a943-476e-89ca-cecf46b5527f.gif).

Comment: Okay, but how does this help me to integrate this?

Comment: Well, $\mbox{work done}=\displaystyle\frac23\int_{\ce{V0}}^{\ce{2V0}}\ce{P}\ \mathrm d\ce{V} = \frac{2\ce{P0}}{3\ce{V0}} \int_{\ce{V0}}^{\ce{2V0}}\ce{V}\ \mathrm d\ce{V} = \frac{2\ce{P0}}{3\ce{V0}} \left(\frac{\ce{V}^2}2\right)_{\ce{V0}}^{\ce{2V0}} = \frac{2\ce{P0}}{3\ce{V0}} \left(\frac{\ce{3V0}^2}2\right)=\ce{P0V0}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45217/discussion-between-kaumudi-harikumar-and-user34388).

Comment: I don't understand how the factor of 2/3 is relevant here. The question is asking for work done not the average kinetic energy of the gas molecules.

Comment: @orthocresol: That's what I've been thinking too... :/

Comment: Your calculation of the area of the trapezoid is the same thing as getting the integral of pdV, aside from the sign  of the result (which has to be taken into account).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is no generic formula for when all three variables are changing at once.

In this case, the easiest way is to simply use the area of a trapezium.

If you insist on integrating, then you need to know what $P$ is as a function of $V$. This derives from basic principles of integration - if you have a function $f(x)$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ gives the area under the curve of $f(x)$ from $x = a$ to $x = b$.

The line $\mathrm{C \rightarrow A}$ can be easily found since the beginning and end points are given. The gradient of the line is

$$m = \frac{2P_0 - P_0}{2V_0 - V_0} = \frac{P_0}{V_0}$$

and the the intercept is clearly 0 from the diagram (you can work it out anyway). In general the equation of a line $y = y(x)$ is given by $y - y_i = m(x - x_i)$ where $(x_i,y_i)$ is any point on the line.

That was perhaps an unnecessarily long explanation but the point is that you now know the relation

$$P = mV$$

holds (where $m$ was determined earlier). Therefore

$$\begin{align}
w &= -\int_{2V_0}^{V_0} P\,\mathrm{d}V \\
&= -\int_{2V_0}^{V_0} -mV\,\mathrm{d}V \\
&= m\left[\frac{1}{2}V^2\right]_{2V_0}^{V_0} \\
&= m\left(\frac{1}{2}V_0^2 - 2V_0^2\right) \\
&= \frac{P_0}{V_0}\left(-\frac{3}{2}V_0^2\right) \\
&= -\frac{3}{2}P_0V_0
\end{align}$$

which is the same as you found via the first method (you also forgot to put the negative sign in the right-hand side of the equation, but I assume that is just a typo).

Comment: I thought you need to multiply by $\dfrac23$ :o

Comment: @user34388: Bit why?

Comment: @user34388 why? The formula you quoted is from the kinetic theory of gases and uses the mean velocity of the gas molecules. It's not relevant to our present question of thermodynamics.

Comment: Yes, I realize that it's not relevant! I was asking @user34388, who quoted it in the first place why it is relevant for our present discussion.

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar I wasn't talking to you.

Comment: Oh, shucks. Sorry :P